# get all data from redis seems slowly

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis

Use spring-data-redis, when I do this action

```
    hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    return hashOperations.values(this.getEntityClass().getName());
    //or use this,the same
    //return hashOperations.entries(this.getEntityClass().getName());
```

it runs so slow, return 10000 objects need 700ms.
if I use memcache, it just need 15ms, so what should I do with spring-data-redis

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible test case? Here's the link to a self-contained test case template: https://gist.github.com/mp911de/73d4b95b04a66eae084395beb25bd499.

Comment: thanks, It's my great honor to ask your question, here is the link.   https://gist.github.com/doublEeVil/86cb9c10d30818440969cf1406d8bf49

Comment: I am wrong , use ehcache need 15ms, not memcached

Comment: In this case the whole comparison does not make any sense. Redis is a remote service while EHCache is a in-memory cache that lives inside the JVM. EHCache requires no I/O (except for replication but that's a different thing).

Comment: thank you, while put or get single  variable in same PC, time difference between redis and ehcache is small, so I think multi get do the same. Thank you very much